# Finding V in a electric field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

How will we find $V_{ab}$  when $\vec E = (2i+3j+4k)$ **N/C** , $\vec R_a = (i-2j+k)$ **m** and $\vec R_b = (2i+j-2k)$ **m** ?
I know $\vec E= -\frac{d V}{d\vec r}$, but I don't know what should be my initial approach toward the question.

Comment: Precisely, E=-(dV/dr); E, r are vectors.

Comment: There is nothing in this question. I mean this question is amazingly easy. What you really need is $\vec E = \frac{dV}{d\vec r}$ and you are saying you already knew it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: $R_{ab}=(-i-3j+3k)m$. So,
$$
V_{ab}=-(2i+3j+4k)\cdot(-i-3j+3k)
$$
or, $V_{ab}= -(-2-9+12)$ volt(s)

or, $V_{ab}= -1$ volt.